# data.foreach() is not a function on d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to d3.js and trying to create a line chart but the problem is that the error `data.foreach()` keeps showing up. I don't know what is the problem. I'm trying to get all the JSON data and loop it so i can draw it on my line chart. And since most of the tutorial or documentation i've seen on the internet is only for csv file. I've tried to create JSON file which i can create a line chart.

This is my js file:

```
$(document).ready(() => {

    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // parse the date / time
    var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y");

    // set the ranges
    var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

    // define the line
    var valueline = d3.line()
        .x(function (d) { return x(d.Date); })
        .y(function (d) { return y(d.Imports); });
    // define the line
    var valueline2 = d3.line()
        .x(function (d) { return x(d.Date); })
        .y(function (d) { return y(d.Exports); });

    // append the svg obgect to the body of the page
    // appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
    // moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform",
            "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    function draw(data) {

        var data = data[0];

        // format the data
        data.forEach(function (d) {
            d.Date = parseTime(d.Date);
            d.Imports = +d.Imports;
            d.Exports = +d.Exports;
        });

        // sort years ascending
        data.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a["Date"] - b["Date"];
        })

        // Scale the range of the data
        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.Date; }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
            return Math.max(d.Imports, d.Exports);
        })]);

        // Add the valueline path.
        svg.append("path")
            .data([data])
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", valueline);
        // Add the valueline path.
        svg.append("path")
            .data([data])
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", valueline2);
        // Add the X Axis
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

        // Add the Y Axis
        svg.append("g")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
    }
    // Get the data

    d3.json("data.json")
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            draw(data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
});
```

and this is my JSON file:

```
[   
       {
          "Date": 1999,
          "Imports": "15",
          "Exports": "20"
       },
       {
          "Date": 2008,
          "Imports": "42",
          "Exports": "115"
       },
       {
          "Date": 2007,
          "Imports": "29",
          "Exports": "79"
       },
       {
          "Date": 2009,
          "Imports": "346",
          "Exports": "324"
       },
       {
          "Date": 2006,
          "Imports": "44",
          "Exports": "69"
       },
       {
          "Date": 2010,
          "Imports": "424",
          "Exports": "503"
       },
       {
          "Date": 2005,
          "Imports": "28",
          "Exports": "48"
       },
       {
          "Date": 2011,
          "Imports": "413",
          "Exports": "603"
       },
       {
          "Date": 2004,
          "Imports": "34",
          "Exports": "41"
       },
       {
          "Date": 2012,
          "Imports": "313",
          "Exports": "517"
       },
       {
          "Date": 2003,
          "Imports": "21",
          "Exports": "36"
       },
       {
          "Date": 2013,
          "Imports": "513",
          "Exports": "615"
       },
       {
          "Date": 2002,
          "Imports": "18",
          "Exports": "23"
       },
       {
          "Date": 2014,
          "Imports": "471",
          "Exports": "766"
       },
       {
          "Date": 2001,
          "Imports": "17",
          "Exports": "29"
       },
       {
          "Date": 2015,
          "Imports": "119",
          "Exports": "181"
       },
       {
          "Date": 2000,
          "Imports": "25",
          "Exports": "25"
       }

   ]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think the `var data = data[0];` of above the forEach should be removed, as you want to loop in all the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to loop in all the array, and then sort it...
Remove the:

```
var data = data[0];
```

before the forEach loop.

Comment: But the error 'data.foreach() is not a function' still shows.